# How to make babel transpile modules linked using "npm link"

Tags: node.js, babeljs, babel-polyfill, babel-loader, babel-register

I have a lot of code in my currently project(my-project) that will be needed in a new one. This code has been written in ES6 and transpiled after with babel.

I've created a module called "my-module" with this shared code and linked it to "my-project" using `npm link`

The problem is that when I start the project, the code from "my-module" is not beening tranpiled and throws an error right at the import statement.

The code inside my-module will be edited a lot. How to make it works?

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon bin/dev",
    "clean": "rm -rf dist",
    "build": "yarn run clean && mkdir dist && babel src -s -d dist",
    "production": "yarn run build && node bin/production"
  },
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-2"]
}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The linked project will not find your `.babelrc` file.  You have a few options:

1. Place a `.babelrc` in `my-project` or a higher level directory.   This will require the babel plugins to be installed in that module though (or globally)
2. If you're using a build tool (i.e. webpack, browserify, etc.) you can declare the babel config there.

This comment helped me out: https://github.com/babel/gulp-babel/issues/93#issuecomment-249172581

My project uses browserify, so declaring the same plugins in the build script that are in `.babelrc` and invoking `require.resolve` caused the npm linked project to be transpiled correctly.

```
return browserify.transform('babelify', {
    sourceMaps: true, 
    global:true, 
    plugins: ['babel-preset-es2015'].map(require.resolve)
})
```