# Babel 6 and Babel 7 support

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, babel-loader

I have a main react published package (cloned locally) which is configured with Babel version 6

```
 "devDependencies" {
   "babel-core": "6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "21.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1"
}
```

with the following config

```
{"presets": ["es2015"] }
```

and Webpack config:

```
...
rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
...
```

And I'm working on a react library component package which is not published which uses Babel version 7

```
  "devDependencies" {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.10",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.10",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.13"
}
  "resolutions": {
     "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0"
},
```

with the following config:

```
  { "presets": ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/env"] }
```

I have installed the react library component package to the main package and I'm getting the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (6:8)

  4 | const Button = () => {
  5 |     return (
> 6 |         <Button>
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: "with the following config:" Is that in a `.babelrc` or a `babel.config.json`?

Comment: So it's clear, Babel configuration inside of the dependency does not matter for building the overall application.

Comment: It's babel.config.json but I also tried with .babelrc

Comment: Hmm wait, I think I misunderstood when I read this originally, your main application, the one actually responsible for building, is using Babel 6, is that right? And are you using `npm link` or something like that to install the component library using v7? Does it end up as a sibling directory?

Comment: yeah the main one is using babel 6 and I'm using npm link to link the component library package. It will be in my node modules after linking

Comment: Seems like this is potentially a duplicate then, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47264802/how-to-make-babel-transpile-modules-linked-using-npm-link Babel6+npm-link is the issue. Babel 7 introduced `babel.config.json` to address exactly this problem in Babel 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Babel 6, `.babelrc` configuration applies specifically to files inside subdirectories of the one containing the `.babelrc`. Since your component library is loaded via `npm link`, it is in a sibling directory, and thus the `.babelrc` does not apply to it.

The only option in Babel 6 is to place your Babel config inside the `webpack.config.js` file, e.g.

```
rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
        }
      },
```

Note also that this config must contain `babel-preset-react`. The fact that your library also has Babel as a dependency and also has a `.babelrc` doesn't affect your overall application build process.

Note, if your primary application were using Babel 7 instead, you'd instead want to rename your primary-application `.babelrc` to be `babel.config.json` instead, and this would have a similar effect to placing the config inside `webpack.config.js` and in fact `babel.config.json` as added in Babel 7 in large part to address exactly the problem you're running into.